# Standard way of importing modules

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I am currently trying to use c++ modules in a code that should compile both on Windows (MSVC) and Linux (Clang and/or GCC).

I am currently developping in Visual Studio and used the "Standard Conformance Mode" (/permissive-) to make my code as portable as possible.

However the following code:

```
import std.core;
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World! haha" << std::endl;

    std::vector<int> myVec{4};

    std::map<std::string, size_t> myMap;

    return 0;
}
```

Can not compile with the /permissive- flag. I get the following error:

> E3223 Cound not find module file "std.core" for import
>
> error C2664: 'int _CrtDbgReport(int,const char *,int,const char
>   *,const char *,...)': cannot convert argument 4 from 'int' to 'const char *'

I tought "std.core" might be a windows-only thing so i tried the following (i saw it in many examples) :

```
import <iostream>;
import <vector>;
import <map>;
```

But it results in the following errors:

> error C7612: could not find header unit for
>   'PATH_TO_VS\include\iostream'
>
> error C7612: could not find header unit for
>   'PATH_TO_VS\include\vector'
>
> error C7612: could not find header unit for 'PATH_TO_VS\include\map'

Note : There are actually files named "iostream", "vector", and "map" in PATH_TO_VS\include.

Therefore i'm wondering what is the standard way of importing c++ modules ? If "import std.core" is the standard way, why doesn't it compile with /permissive- ?

I am using Visual Studio 2019 (Community) and CMake.

Edit:

Sorry i forgot to tell my compiler flags:

```
/experimental:module
/std:c++latest
/W4
/WX
/permissive-
/MDd
/EHsc
```

The code compiles without /permissive-, but does not when it is set. I can't figure out why

Comment: `std.core` isn't a Windows thing.

Comment: Only the `import<>` syntax is part of C++20 for the standard library.  (User-written modules can be used via `import foo;`.)

Answer (score 14):

According to Microsoft Docs, import headers are not yet implemented. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-160#imported-header-files.

You can following the progress on this feature here: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/60.

You can use the `import std.core;` syntax in Visual Studio 2019 (I tested this with v16.8+) but you will also need to install the "**C++ Modules for v142 build tools**" component in the Visual Studio Installer for this to work.

In addition, you will need to enable the following flags:

- `/std:c++latest`
- `/experimental:module`

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59447526/12089150).

You may still get some `C5050` warnings about incompatible environment while importing the `std.core` module:

```
1>C:\Test\C++\Modules\main.cpp(1,16): warning C5050: Possible incompatible environment while importing module 'std.core': _GUARDOVERFLOW_CRT_ALLOCATORS=1 is defined in current command line and not in module command line
1>C:\Test\C++\Modules\main.cpp(1,16): warning C5050: Possible incompatible environment while importing module 'std.core': _DEBUG is defined in current command line and not in module command line
1>C:\Test\C++\Modules\main.cpp(1,16): warning C5050: Possible incompatible environment while importing module 'std.core': _M_FP_PRECISE is defined in current command line and not in module command line
```

1. To solve the first warning change **SDL Checks** to **No** (`/sdl-`).
2. To solve the second warning, remove the `_DEBUG` preprocessor definition.
3. To solve the third warning, delete the value of the **Floating Point Model** (which was, by default, set to `/fp:precise` in my case).

Comment: I had a similar problem. Instead of disabling **SDL Checks**, I disabled the warnings with `#pragma warning(disable: 5050)` and `#pragma warning(disable: 4996)`

Answer (score 4):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=vs-2019
you need to use compiler switches

- /experimental:module
- /std:c++latest
- /EHsc
- /MD

As well as configuring experimental modules support for the project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I'm using the flags you mentionned and installed the c++ modules support when configuring Visual Studio.

Could you explain what you mean by " configuring experimental modules support for the project." ? I am new to programming with Visual Studio and since i'm using CMake i didn't have to configure anything more so far.

Comment: If you go read the link, it says "In a Visual Studio project, right-click the project node in Solution Explorer and choose Properties. Set the Configuration drop-down to All Configurations, then choose Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Language > Enable C++ Modules (experimental)."

Comment: Happy Xmas to you. Unfortunately i had to remove the flag /permissive-. I'll do whithout it :)

Comment: Don't forget also to actually install the c++ new module libraries or no compiler switches will save your soul :)