# Can't use iostream as module in C++20 (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, c++20

I can't get this code running in the newest version of [MSVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B). This code example is from the book called *"Beginning C++20, From Novice to Professional"* by Ivor Horton and Peter Van Weert.

```
import <iostream>;

int main()
{
    int answer {42};
    std::cout << "The answer to life, universe, and everything is "
              << answer
              << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

> could not find header unit for 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\iostream'

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio version 16.8.1, and have enabled these flags in project properties (according to the similar question *[Standard way of importing modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59447206/standard-way-of-importing-modules)*):

- /experimental:module
- /std:c++latest
- /EHsc
- /MD

Should I use [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) or [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) instead?

Comment: As of October 29th, 2020, the instructions on [how to use modules in Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/a-tour-of-cpp-modules-in-visual-studio/#getting-started-with-modules-in-visual-studio) only mention `/std:c++latest`. Can you try again after disabling the other flags? Especially `/experimental:module` might interfere

Comment: Still got the same error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\iostream" is not an importable header

Comment: The October 29th, 2020 instructions in the above link don't appear to use any of the std library as a module. It still uses `#include <iostream>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The authors stated in the example and solution files provided for download, that due to compilers' implementations of the C++20-standard the files might not work yet (see [the book's page](https://www.apress.com/9781484258835) for details and [corresponding GitHub repository](https://github.com/Apress/beginning-cpp20)).

Therefore they provide "no modules" examples which use the "#include" directive.

Answer (score 11):

**Using the [Visual Studio 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2019) non preview version:**

1. Create an empty C++ project
2. Open project properties: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Go to *Configuration Properties* → *C/C++* → *Language*, and set the *C++ Language Standard* option to *Preview - Features from the Latest C++*
4. In the same section, set *Enable Experimental C++ Standard Library Modules* to *Yes (/experimental:module)*
5. Go to *Configuration Properties* → *C/C++* → *Advanced* and set the *Compile As* option to *Compile as C++ Module Internal Partition (/internalPartition)*
6. Add header file to your project, which contains an import declaration for every standard library header you want to import. For example:

   ```
   #pragma once
   import <iostream>;
   import <array>;
   import <vector>;
   ```
7. Recompile your project
8. Done, now everything should work fine

Comment: Possible errata in [this "answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64877559/cant-use-iostream-as-module-in-c20-visual-studio/71696204#71696204).

Comment: Now deleted. It contains *"This will work: 5. Go to Configuration Properties → C/C++ → Advanced and set the Compile As option to Compile as C++ Module Code (/interface)"*

Answer (score 1):

Some settings in Visual Studio have changed and support for C++ 20 has improved (checked with Visual Studio 2022 v 17.7.6 and 17.9.0).

Set the following in the project properties:

[Property Language Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM8kd.png)

[Property Advanced Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4C1L.png)

**'Configuration Properties' -> 'C/C++' -> 'Language'**

> C++ Language Standard -> ISO C++20 Standard (/std:c++20)
> Enable Experimental C++ Standard Library Modules -> Yes (/experimental:module)

'*Build ISO C++ 23 Standard Library Modules*' isn't actually required for this example, but you may try enable that also

**'Configuration Properties' -> 'C/C++' -> 'Advanced'**

> Compile As -> Compile as C++ Module Code (/interface )

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be fairly decent support for modules in MSVC now with and without CMake (presumably at this point clang as well). I can't exactly speak for clang, I've only just played around with MSVC and modules recently.

Unfortunately I've found that even though I've installed the required build tools there seems to be an issue where the MSVC compiler doesn't pick up on the fact there are system modules. Normally resulting in errors complaining that some expected module related file doesn't exist (which they most certainly should) or something to that effect. And then confusingly if I use the MSVC IDE I can import those same headers in other projects no problem, so why the IDE can figure this out I have to assume is due to extra configuration options I'm simply not aware of pointing it to the required files.

It seems you can potentially get the compiler to generate those files or whatever it is missing by using the typical `#include <system_header>` syntax first.

```c
module;
#include <iostream>;
//I didn't test this, but my suspicion is that some functionality of the include has to be used in some portion of the export in order to generate the files missing.
//What I'm imagining is happening is that work is being done to
//treat the contents of the #include like a module, leaving behind files that can later be imported
export module some_module;

export {
}
```

And then, after successfully building (without errors), there's a chance replacing the syntax back with import may work. I've not had 100% success rate with this with other system headers. I know `<vector>`, `<iostream>` and `<string>` specifically can work. I wish this worked reliably so that in theory it'd be a relatively quick fix, unfortunately I think it's still a waiting game for modules to be reliably supported. Hopefully* this helps someone as frustrated as I was in the meantime.

Edit: I'm now slightly more confident my theory was correct, I just had MSVC complaining that `import <string>;` was a problem, I went and made a dummy module which included `<string>` and exported a function which used `std::string` which I then called in the main function and now after building suddenly `import <string>;` works as well.

Answer (score -2):

Try to do it like this:

```
import <iostream>;         // import declaration
```

Modules help divide large amounts of code into logical parts.
Modules are orthogonal to namespaces.

**Example**:

#### File helloworld.cpp

```
export module helloworld;  // module declaration
import <iostream>;         // import declaration

export void hello() {      // export declaration
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
}
```

#### File main.cpp

```
import helloworld;  // import declaration

int main() {
    hello();
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work. IntelliSense highlights red iostream for me.

Comment: Does it compile though? Intellisense is not always correct.

Comment: Nah. I can't even compile that. Still got the same error. Idk, maybe GCC and Clang are a better solution for this? Even authors of book reminded me, that some of these new features maybe not supported
But, lol, IntelliSense highlights the keyword import, so, idk

Comment: I just tested and it did not work for me either however I am not at `16.8.1` yet and I don't want to risk upgrading being that there is not an easy way to downgrade again without restore points or backup and restore.