# Can I use module support or an import feature to avoid including massive c++ standard library headers?

Tags: c++, import

If I write a class in a header and I want to use something like std::is_integral I need to include <type_traits> in the header itself. This means that wherever I use my class I also include (I think it's 4000 lines) of code included from <type_traits> and the headers it includes. If it's a class I include only 5 times in my project that's 20,000 lines of code extra in my project to compile. Correct me if I'm wrong but the compiler parses every single character of those 20,000 lines, not just parts of the header that I use (called functions etc.). When I mean parse, I don't mean compile, but it at least has to do whatever it does to notice errors in the code. I've noticed that when I start a new project compilation times are very good, but compilation times blow up really dramatically just after a few additions, and I have a feeling that doing things like this (compiling thousands of lines of code unnecessarily) is the reason for this.

I tried workarounds, like for example in one case I needed std::remove_reference, and to avoid including 4000 lines of code just provided my own version of it, but in some cases you can't. In a case where I need a standard library class or function, say something std::is_integral, do I absolutely have to include all of the header or is there support for importing just that class/template? Does C++ modules support this?

Comment: You could try pre-compiled headers, and add the Standard Library headers that you use to it.

Comment: One of the driving forces for **modules** is reducing this kind of overhead, improving build times, reducing ripple dependency effects, reducing unnecessary identifier "pollution", and reducing the need for (external) header files.  While also being able to migrate to modules incrementally, rather than all-or-nothing.  Doubtlessly using other languages for inspiration, like Java/JVM/jar and C#/.NET.

Comment: @Eljay I've tried but it doesn't seem like doing import <iostream> works.

Comment: It could be a limitation of your compiler's **modules** support, according to [compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) support seems a bit behind (may be a difficult to implement compiler feature).  For example, [Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64877559/cant-use-iostream-as-module-in-c20-visual-studio).