# Error when importing <string> and <iostream> in same file with clang++-16

Tags: c++, c++20, clang++, libc++, c++-modules

I get a compilation error when trying to import `<string>` and `<iostream>` in the same file. Is there any known way around this?

This is what I have tried this far. (based on instructions from [clang](https://releases.llvm.org/15.0.0/tools/clang/docs/StandardCPlusPlusModules.html))

```bash
clang++-16 -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ -xc++-system-header --precompile "/usr/lib/llvm-16/include/c++/v1/iostream"  -o  "build/.mm3/default/iostream.pcm" -Wno-pragma-system-header-outside-header -Wno-user-defined-literals 
clang++-16 -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ -xc++-system-header --precompile "/usr/lib/llvm-16/include/c++/v1/string"  -o  "build/.mm3/default/string.pcm" -Wno-pragma-system-header-outside-header -Wno-user-defined-literals 
clang++-16 -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ "apa.cpp"  -fmodule-file="build/.mm3/default/iostream.pcm" -fmodule-file="build/.mm3/default/string.pcm"  -c -o  "build/.mm3/default/apa.o"
```

```cpp
// apa.cpp
import <iostream>;
import <string>;

int print() {
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    return 10;
}
```

The error message I get is

```bash
In module '/usr/lib/llvm-16/include/c++/v1/iostream':
/usr/lib/llvm-16/bin/../include/c++/v1/string_view:301:5: error: 'std::basic_string_view<char>::basic_string_view' from module '/usr/lib/llvm-16/include/c++/v1/iostream' is not present in definition of 'std::string_view' in module '/usr/lib/llvm-16/include/c++/v1/string'
    basic_string_view(const _CharT* __s, size_type __len) _NOEXCEPT
    ^
/usr/lib/llvm-16/bin/../include/c++/v1/string_view:267:5
: note: definition has no member 'basic_string_view'
    basic_string_view {
    ^
In module '/usr/lib/llvm-16/include/c++/v1/iostream':
/usr/lib/llvm-16/bin/../include/c++/v1/string_view:295:5: error: 'std::basic_string_view<char>::basic_string_view' from module '/usr/lib/llvm-16/include/c++/v1/iostream' is not present in definition of 'std::string_view' in module '/usr/lib/llvm-16/include/c++/v1/string'
    basic_string_view(const basic_string_view&) _NOEXCEPT = default;
    ^
/usr/lib/llvm-16/bin/../include/c++/v1/string_view:267:5: note: definition has no member 'basic_string_view'
    basic_string_view {
    ^
In module '/usr/lib/llvm-16/include/c++/v1/iostream':
/usr/lib/llvm-16/bin/../include/c++/v1/string_view:292:5: error: 'std::basic_string_view<char>::basic_string_view' from module '/usr/lib/llvm-16/include/c++/v1/iostream' is not present in definition of 'std::string_view' in module '/usr/lib/llvm-16/include/c++/v1/string'
    basic_string_view() _NOEXCEPT : __data_ (nullptr), __size_(0) {}
    ^
/usr/lib/llvm-16/bin/../include/c++/v1/string_view:267:5: note: definition has no member 'basic_string_view'
    basic_string_view {
    ^
In module '/usr/lib/llvm-16/include/c++/v1/iostream':
/usr/lib/llvm-16/bin/../include/c++/v1/string_view:312:37: error: 'std::basic_string_view<char>::basic_string_view' from module '/usr/lib/llvm-16/include/c++/v1/iostream' is not present in definition of 'std::string_view' in module '/usr/lib/llvm-16/include/c++/v1/string'
    constexpr _LIBCPP_HIDE_FROM_ABI basic_string_view(_It __begin, _End __end)
                                    ^
/usr/lib/llvm-16/bin/../include/c++/v1/string_view:267:5: note: definition has no member 'basic_string_view'
    basic_string_view {
    ^
In module '/usr/lib/llvm-16/include/c++/v1/iostream':
/usr/lib/llvm-16/bin/../include/c++/v1/string_view:339:5: 
error: 'std::basic_string_view<char>::basic_string_view' from module '/usr/lib/llvm-16/include/c++/v1/iostream' is not present in definition of 'std::string_view' in module '/usr/lib/llvm-16/include/c++/v1/string'
    basic_string_view(const _CharT* __s)
    ^
...
```

Edit: A temporary workaround seems to be to never import `<string>`. `<iostream>` seems to include std::string at the same time. So for now it seems like I will just change that, until the bug is fixed.

"Working" (compiling) example:

```cpp
import <iostream>;
// import <string>;

int print() {
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    std::string str = "satnhoeu";
    return 10;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the bug tracking system? That should be something noticed and fixed quickly.

Comment: Maybe I should try that, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Have you tested this code using only one import?

Comment: Yes one import works. You can import string or iostream, but not both

Comment: @PatricioLoncomilla I need to correct myself there. It seems like importing iostream does not work by itself either. I thought I tested for it yesterday, but now it does not work.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt fyi https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/58540

Comment: Related: [Learning C++20: import <iostream>; error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72075085/learning-c20-import-iostream-error)

Comment: @JasonLiam Thanks but no. That question is by a beginner who does not know that c++20 features does not work in GCC, My question is about the latest version of clang++ and libc++

Comment: @Lasersköld I agree. I just wanted to put that link here so that if any beginner comes across either of these posts, they can see the other.